# How to change the date format which is displayed in the calendar from 24 hours to 12 hours in wdcalendar?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

In the calendar the time is displayed in 24 hour format. I need to change it as 12 hour format.

The first column of the calendar will be display the time.
It starts with 00:00, 01:00 ................ 23:00.
I need to replace it with 00:00 am .... 11:00 am 12:00 pm ...... 11:00 pm

http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-plugins-demo/wdCalendar/sample.php

Comment: Can you give an example of some time (in the final format you have now) and the desired output?

Comment: When I post an event for 1 pm - 2 pm in the calendar it shows the time as 13:00 - 14:00. I want to change it to 1:00 pm - 2:00 pm. I'm not sure where to change it. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the source and the function `BuildDayEvent` is what you are looking for (located in `jquery.calendar.js`. It has two variables `p.starttime` and `p.endtime`. If you have experience with javascript, it should not be difficult to switch this to 12h instead of 24h

Comment: The time is displayed using this for loop, for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
                tmt = fomartTimeShow(i);
                ht.push("<div style=\"height: 41px\" class=\"tg-time\">", tmt, "</div>");
            } and the formatTimeShow function is function fomartTimeShow(h) {
            return h < 10 ? "0" + h + ":00" : h + ":00";
        }

Comment: I am not sure how to change it. Could you please help me.